Difficulty Grabbing XHR Endpoint Response using Playwright and SeleniumBase
I've been having some trouble with a website using Pyppeteer, although it's working smoothly with Playwright and SeleniumBase. My main challenge is figuring out how to retrieve the XHR endpoint response from the networks tab after visiting the original endpoint using these tools.
For instance, when I visit a URL on UberEats, I notice an API (https://www.ubereats.com/_p/api/getFeedV1?localeCode=en-US) with a JSON response in the networks tab. It contains useful cookies and parameters obtained after visiting the original URL. How can I retrieve this URL from the network responses, specifically in the Fetch/XHR tab?
Any tips or advice you have would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
I don't find any solutions to get the XHR endpoints using Playwright or SeleniumBase, which works for many blocked websites in my case.

Can you share your working code and attempt at the non-working code? Your question seems to contradict itself: first you say Playwright and SeleniumBase are "working smoothly", then you say you can't find any solutions using those technologies...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
